# Where is Type.GetCustomAttributes method in CoreCLR?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, asp.net-core, coreclr

I am trying to get attributes from a class, and it seems that there is no GetCustomAttributes method. How to obtain attributes in CoreCLR?

```
using System.Reflection;

class FooBar {
    FooBar() {
        GetType().GetCustomAttributes(); // does not compile
        GetType().GetField("test").GetCustomAttributes(); // compiles
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `TypeInfo`, you get it by `Type.GetTypeInfo()` which is a extension method from the `System.Reflection` namespace.

This has been [changed with .NET 4.5.](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/11/29/typeinfo-reflection.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Add the the [System.Reflection Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Reflection/4.1.0-beta-23516), then use `.GetTypeInfo().CustomAttributes`